# arm compiler error undefined reference to `__libc_init_array'

Tags: gcc, arm, ld, arm64

I am trying to compile a C program which utilizes dl library to access shared object functions from a dynamic library I created.
The code is very simple and from a tutorial.

I initially compiled it on x86 platform using gcc with no issues.

I am now trying to compile it for arm platform and I am getting an error.

I tried using the following to compile it

> arm-none-eabi-gcc -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include -L/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib ex29.c -ldl -o ex29

I get the following error:

> /usr/local/share/gcc-arm-none-eabi-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.4.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/crt0.o: In function `_start':
>   (.text+0xe0): undefined reference to`__libc_init_array'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I am not sure what is causing this error.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `__libc_init_array` is a function in libc that runs constructors (and static C++ ctors if that's the case). You're not linking a libc.

Comment: On a second look, you're compiling with a `arm-none-eabi` GCC and `arm-linux-gnueabi` libs and includes. `none-eabi` means bare metal. Since you're talking about dynamic libraries, I assume you're building for ARM Linux. Get yourself a `arm-linux-gnueabi` toolchain.

Comment: Any solution to this error? The query is still unanswered.